# sun.security.pkcs11 is not visible

Tags: java, softhsm

Error:

```
SoftHSM.java:8: error: package sun.security.pkcs11 is not visible
import sun.security.pkcs11.*;
                   ^
  (package sun.security.pkcs11 is declared in module jdk.crypto.cryptoki, which is not in the module graph)
```

[image: Error log screenshot]

Unable to run SoftHSM.java program to work with softHSM due to the errors.

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.*;

import java.security.*;
import java.security.interfaces.*;
import java.security.cert.*;
import sun.security.pkcs11.*;
import org.bouncycastle.x509.*;

import javax.security.auth.x500.X500Principal;

import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.BasicConstraints;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.ExtendedKeyUsage;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.GeneralName;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.GeneralNames;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.KeyPurposeId;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.KeyUsage;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.X509Extensions;
import org.bouncycastle.x509.X509V3CertificateGenerator;

class SoftHSM
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        // Set up the Sun PKCS 11 provider
        String configName = "softhsm.cfg";
        Provider p = new SunPKCS11(configName);

        if (-1 == Security.addProvider(p)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("could not add security provider");
        }

        // Load the key store
        char[] pin = "1234".toCharArray();
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11", p);
        ks.load(null, pin);

        // Generate the key
        SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();
        KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", p);
        keyGen.initialize(1024, sr);
        KeyPair keyPair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
        PrivateKey pk = keyPair.getPrivate();

        // Java API requires a certificate chain
        X509Certificate[] chain = generateV3Certificate(keyPair);

        ks.setKeyEntry("ALIAS-GOES-HERE", pk, "1234".toCharArray(), chain);

        ks.store(null);

        System.out.println("OK");
    }


    public static X509Certificate[] generateV3Certificate(KeyPair pair) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchProviderException, SignatureException {
        Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());

        X509V3CertificateGenerator certGen = new X509V3CertificateGenerator();

        certGen.setSerialNumber(BigInteger.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        certGen.setIssuerDN(new X500Principal("CN=Test Certificate"));
        certGen.setNotBefore(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 10000));
        certGen.setNotAfter(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000));
        certGen.setSubjectDN(new X500Principal("CN=Test Certificate"));
        certGen.setPublicKey(pair.getPublic());
        certGen.setSignatureAlgorithm("SHA256WithRSA");

        certGen.addExtension(X509Extensions.BasicConstraints, true, new BasicConstraints(false));
        certGen.addExtension(X509Extensions.KeyUsage, true, new KeyUsage(KeyUsage.digitalSignature | KeyUsage.keyEncipherment));
        certGen.addExtension(X509Extensions.ExtendedKeyUsage, true, new ExtendedKeyUsage(KeyPurposeId.id_kp_serverAuth));

        certGen.addExtension(X509Extensions.SubjectAlternativeName, false, new GeneralNames(new GeneralName(GeneralName.rfc822Name, "test@test.test")));

        X509Certificate[] chain = new X509Certificate[1];
        chain[0] = certGen.generateX509Certificate(pair.getPrivate(), "SunPKCS11-SoftHSM");

        return chain;
    }
}
```

```
name = SoftHSM
library = C:/SoftHSM2/lib/softhsm2-x64.dll
slot = 0x0
attributes(generate, *, *) = {
   CKA_TOKEN = true
}
attributes(generate, CKO_CERTIFICATE, *) = {
   CKA_PRIVATE = false
}
attributes(generate, CKO_PUBLIC_KEY, *) = {
   CKA_PRIVATE = false
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because some changes have been happened between versions of java.
You have two alternatives:

1. Change version of source code, for example with maven you can add these properties to your pom file.

   ```
   <properties>
       <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
       <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
   </properties>
   ```
2. Use providers:

   ```
   Provider sunPKCS11 = Security.getProvider("SunPKCS11");
   sunPKCS11 = sunPKCS11.configure("softhsm.cfg");
   KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11", sunPKCS11);
   ```

And erase this line "import sun.security.pkcs11.*;". Maybe you have to upgrade bouncycastle too.